# Makefile generator for c++?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, bjam

Do the following build systems: cmake, jam and bjam also generate makefiles like qmake does?  What utility does MS visual c++ uses to generate make file?

Comment: hm, again.  Could you, please, take a look here and leave a note why you tagged this [makefile]? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make

Comment: Is makefile not right word?Have a look http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefiles .Am i missing something?

Comment: The title of the manual you referenced is "GNU `make`".  Makefile is a right word for *a file*, but you don't tag C++-concerned questions with [cpp-file] tag, do you?

Comment: If so it has to be make file and not makefile !!!

Comment: @yesraaj , unless it was a joke, I would really like to listen to your elaborated arguments on meta, at the page I linked above.

Comment: I am really not concern about making it make/makefile unless everyone understand I am talking about general makefile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CMake does generate makefiles and projects files for several different build systems on different platforms. CMake is more generalised than qmake, which is specialised for Qt projects.

jam and bjam are replacements for make, i.e. different syntax. They do not generate build files.

You can generate makefiles (that nmake can use) from Visual Studio by saving them out once you have generated a solution.

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio has its own project file format (*.vcproj), which CMake can generate. CMake can also generate Makefiles.

I can highly recommend CMake.

Comment: is jam and bjam do generate makefiles?

Comment: Is it jam use there own version of makefile(jamfile) that jam can build the source using it?

Comment: Jam/bjam has their own syntax ("Jamfiles"). Sorry, but I don't understand your second comment.

Comment: I am trying to mean the same, that jam has its own syntax for jamfiles(configuration file,something like makefile for make but precise) that can be used to build the src + includes to executable

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at [premake](http://premake.sourceforge.net/about). Not sure if it does what qmake does, but it does generate project / make files for several tools.

Comment: Actually I am not looking for a makefile generator but to know whether jam and bjam are one of them.

Comment: Jam and Bjam do **not** generate Makefiles.